AWS CLI command completions for zsh
I want to use the AWS CLI v2 with zsh command completion.
There are instructions here, but they refer to a file aws_zsh_completer.sh which does not exist in the downloaded zip file, nor in /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/. Possibly those docs are outdated.
How does one set up zsh completions?

FYI I see it here in the repo. There's also an open issue here. Ah, you raised it :-) That's what I would have done.

Just use file from repository

I think the issue is the completion script is missing from the install file. Until that's fixed, I'm using this workaround:
$ AWSCLI_VERSION=$(aws --version | sed -E 's/^aws-cli\/(.+) Python.*/\1/')
$ sudo curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/refs/heads/master/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh' \
  -o "/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/$AWSCLI_VERSION/dist/aws_zsh_completer.sh"
$ echo "source /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/$AWSCLI_VERSION/dist/aws_zsh_completer.sh" >> ~/.zshrc

Please upvote the bug report so that they fix the issue.

this does not work on Sonoma 14.6 that folder does not exist, and why not just put it in your profile anyway?

@kevinc This is for linux. I put the file where it is supposed to be, assuming that the installer were fixed. The docs I linked to above show macos instructions, which should be very similar.
